# Can't do a POST call with Pytest, Jenkins and Flask

Tags: python, json, post, jenkins, pytest

I can't create a post call with a flask service. Here's my code:

```
def test_post_create_file(client):
        fileContent = {'filename': 'TestName', 'content': 'TestContent'}
        client.post('/v1.0/files', data = json.dumps(fileContent))
```

The POST function:

```
@app.route('/v1.0/files',methods=['POST'])
def read_create_file():
  cont = request.get_json(silent=True)
  file = cont['filename']
  content = cont['content']
  if not file or not content:
    return "empty file or content", 404
  if create_file(file, content):
    return "CREATED", 200
```

The Exception:

```
Error Message

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is unsubscriptable

Trace

client = <FlaskClient <Flask 'e'>>

    def test_post_create_file(client):
        fileContent = {'filename': 'ArchivoPrueba', 'content': 'ContenidoPrueba'}
>       client.post('/v1.0/files', data = json.dumps(fileContent))

test_e.py:24:
```

I believe it has something to do with trying to access the json object as an array, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the answer:

```
def test_post_create_file(client):
        fileContent = {'filename': 'ArchivoPrueba', 'content': 'ContenidoPrueba'}
        client.post('/v1.0/files', data = json.dumps(fileContent), content_type='application/json')
```

The content_type parameter was missing.